# Hiding tab bar items on xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, uitabbarcontroller

So i have a tab bar controller linked to 4 different view controllers. 
My first viewcontroller (First page that pops up during simulation) is my login page. I just want to hide the tab bar items before logging in and after the right login details have been entered re-enable the tab bar items to be accessible.
I have read other related questions in this site however i can't seem to find a simple solution. I thought the coding would be as easy as hiding images or labels.

any help will be great!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
//To hide the tab bar
self.tabBar.hidden = YES;

//To disable tab bar item in tab bar controller
[[[[self.tabBarController tabBar]items]objectAtIndex:1]setEnabled:FALSE];
```

Comment: Okay is there a reason why all tab bar items get disabled except for one of them?

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    credentialsDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"password",@"12345",nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"username",@"chris",nil]];
    [[[[self.tabBarController tabBar]items]objectAtIndex:1]setEnabled:FALSE];
}

Comment: because you have added code to disable tab bar item at index 1

Comment: so do i have to disable all other indexes as well? index = 1 is the firstviewcontroller?

Comment: Yes, you can disable items using index. And let me know if it is working or not

Comment: Okay so i am not quite understanding this but this is what i did:
 [[[[self.tabBarController tabBar]items]objectAtIndex:1]setEnabled:FALSE];
    [[[[self.tabBarController tabBar]items]objectAtIndex:2]setEnabled:FALSE];
    [[[[self.tabBarController tabBar]items]objectAtIndex:3]setEnabled:FALSE];

Comment: actually nevermind solved the problem! BIG HELP THANKS!!

Comment: @ChrisChoi, If my code is helped you then you should accept as an answer, marking an answer with a 'check mark' is expected StackOverflow behavior.